# Why aren't my WordPress category posts listing on their category pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been spinning my wheels on this problem for way too long and I'm running out of time. So I turn to you, Stack Users.

Some background: This site omits certain categories depending on how you've chosen to view the site. Middle/High School users see certain categories and posts, Adult Ed users see posts and categories that MS/HS students don't. The first part of this function works. The rest do not and I cannot figure out why. The first part of the function filters out the necessary posts, including events and videos. The last two conditions restore them if you're on their respective category pages. Or, it should. That's the intention. It isn't.

```
function filter_posts( $query ) {
if ( ( $query->is_home() || is_category() ) && $query->is_main_query() ) :
    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['branch'] ) ) :
        $postsToExclude = array('15','10','16');
        if ( $_COOKIE['branch'] == 'middle-high-school' ) :
            array_push($postsToExclude, '69','36','70');
        elseif ( $_COOKIE['branch'] == 'adult-education' ) :
            array_push($postsToExclude, '35', '40', '68', '36','70');
        endif;

        $query->set( 'category__not_in', $postsToExclude );
    endif;
endif;

if ( $query->is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query() ) :
    // We also need to exclude the featured post from the main blog feed.
    $custom_meta[] = array(
        'key' => 'blog_feature_this',
        'value' => '"Yes"',
        'compare' => 'NOT IN'
    );
    $query->set('meta_query', $custom_meta);
endif;

if ( is_category( 'events' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) :
    $query->set( 'category__in', array(10) );
endif;

if ( is_category( 'videos' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) :
    $query->set( 'category__in', array(16) );
endif;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts' );
```

Comment: Just out of interest why not just use category__not_in and remove the ids from the array in your conditionals - then at the end do your query->set with the final $postsToExclude array. Otherwise you have a conflicting query saying posts not in this category and in this category - which makes no sense.

Comment: @SimonPollard It just seemed like less code. Creating an array at the beginning and then pushing some values depending on the cookie value seemed a more efficient way to write this. Moving the array into the conditions achieves the same end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this instead - using just the one parameter and adjusting the array of values as needed.

```
function filter_posts( $query ) {

  // Define the array
  $postsToExclude = array();

  if ( ( $query->is_home() || is_category() ) && $query->is_main_query() ) :
      if ( isset( $_COOKIE['branch'] ) ) :
          $postsToExclude = array('15','10','16');
          if ( $_COOKIE['branch'] == 'middle-high-school' ) :
              array_push($postsToExclude, '69','36','70');
          elseif ( $_COOKIE['branch'] == 'adult-education' ) :
              array_push($postsToExclude, '35', '40', '68', '36','70');
          endif;
      endif;
  endif;

  if ( $query->is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query() ) :
      // We also need to exclude the featured post from the main blog feed.
      $custom_meta[] = array(
          'key' => 'blog_feature_this',
          'value' => '"Yes"',
          'compare' => 'NOT IN'
      );
      $query->set('meta_query', $custom_meta);
  endif;

  if ( is_category( 'events' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) :
    // If the category is in the exclude list remove it
    if(array_key_exists('10',$postsToExclude)) {
      unset($postsToExclude['10'];
    }
  endif;

  if ( is_category( 'videos' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) :
    // If the category is in the exclude list remove it
    if(array_key_exists('10',$postsToExclude)) {
      unset($postsToExclude['16'];
    }
  endif;

  // If there are some values
  if(!empty($postsToExclude)) {
    $query->set( 'category__not_in', $postsToExclude );
  }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts' );
```

Comment: Still not working (has to be something in my conditions) but I see what you did there and you're totally right. I had critical conflicts in my query. Your version is better.

Comment: Glad to be of some help, just wanted to write it down in a way that made sense when speaking it out - the checks are just force of habit and always worth having in.